# tengo codigo incrustado en mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hace unas semanas ese código aparece en mi proyecto que esta en hostinguer pero en mi proyecto local no lo visualizo estuvo operando bien por mas de un año alguien que pueda ayudarme

Comment: Si no aparece en su proyecto local y solo aparece en la web, edite su archivo index desde el administrador de ficheros de Hostinger.

Comment: Lo raro es que elimine todo y volvi a cargar el proyecto funciona bien como una semana y después vuelve aparecer ese código